# Setting Config File not working in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Setting Config File not working. I have tried setting the config file paypal as below. It does not update the config variable payment_definition_amount.
Why I am not able to set the config file
    class PlanController extends Controller
    {

```
public function updatePlan(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'plan_id' => 'required|string',
    ]);
    Config::set(['paypal.payment_definition_amount'=>$request['payment_definition_amount']]);
    config('paypal.payment_definition_amount', $request['payment_definition_amount']);
    return ['message' => "Success",'payment_amount' =>$request['payment_definition_amount']];
}
}
```

**Paypal Config**

```
 return [
'plan_id' => 'P-2A5761613A054890GVEZMPLY',
'plan_name'=> 'Monthly Billing Plan',
'plan_type'=>  'FIXED',
'payment_definition_type' => 'REGULAR',
'payment_definition_frequency' => 'Month',
'payment_definition_currency' => 'USD',
'payment_definition_amount' => 100,
'payment_definition_cycles' => '12',
'payment_definition_frequency_interval' => '2',
 ];
```

Comment: if you `dd(config('paypal.payment_definition_amount'))` right before your return, you don't see the updated value?

Comment: It is not working

Comment: @Mozammil I see the updated value

Comment: I see the update amount but not return to the paypal file

Comment: It won't override the value in the file.Using `Config::set()` will only override the value for the duration of the current request.

Comment: I did understand what you are saying

Comment: How to update the value in the file